# Getting Warning with Docker on

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

When I do "docker-compose up -d" with the yaml file below, my redis image gives me the warning below.

```
WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

I think I need to somehow add it to the "command" in my docker-compose.yaml file but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
redis:
  image: redis:4.0.5-alpine
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 6379:6379
  expose:
    - 6379
  command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
  hostname: redis
  networks:
    - web
  volumes:
    - redis-data:/data
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `transparent_hugepage` is kernel feature, you can do nothing in compose, you should follow the indication to disable it in your host system's bash with root.

```
$ echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

To make it also effect after reboot, you should write it to `/etc/rc.local` which will run again after your host reboot.

As you know, the container will share the host's kernel when run, with above disable in host, your container will then also benifit from the modification.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  on my server (digitalocean), I don't have rc.local in my /etc directory. I do see rc0.d.  Sorry for not knowing my way around linux.

Comment: Yeah, you could put it in any startup file of your linux.

Comment: How do I make this change to the host on Docker for Windows?

Comment: I don't know how did it for linux container on windows as I don't know how to operate that hyperv directly. What I can thought is: a new dockerfile extends from redis, in this new image use a entrypoint.sh. In this entrypoint.sh, add `echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`, then add the redis start command?